# One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts

Tags: android

In lib  com.thingclips.smart of tuya have 1 error  One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts of  but I can't fix it.This is version 5.1.0 .
I encountered this problem on Android 14 During runtime.Can you help me?

+I found the latest version which is 5.1.0 but it didn't solve the problem.
+
Tuya library also does not mention this on Android 14.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As discussed at Google I/O 2023, registering receivers with intention using the RECEIVER_EXPORTED / RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED flag was introduced as part of Android 13 and is now a requirement for apps running on Android 14 or higher (U+).

If you do not implement this, the system will throw a security exception.

To allow the broadcast receiver to receive broadcasts from other apps, register the receiver using the following code:

```
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
```

To register a broadcast receiver that does not receive broadcasts from other apps, including system apps, register the receiver using the following code:

```
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED);
```

Note: That call will need minSdkVersion to be 26 (Android 8) al least

Check [https://www.delasign.com/blog/android-studio-kotlin-broadcast-recievers-export-or-not/#:~:text=As%20discussed%20at%20Google%20I,will%20throw%20a%20security%20exception](https://www.delasign.com/blog/android-studio-kotlin-broadcast-recievers-export-or-not/#:%7E:text=As%20discussed%20at%20Google%20I,will%20throw%20a%20security%20exception).

Comment: Let me add a small addition to your answer: in order to avoid the API 26 limitation, you can use ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, br, filter, receiverFlags). More details here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers

Comment: I am using LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(eventsReceiver,filter); and it don't have flags to pass. 

package androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content;

Comment: Note that older versions of some Android libraries may also call registerReceiver without including the mandatory flag and trigger the security exception.  For example, if your app is using an older version of the Google Play Billing API, the BillingClient https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient can crash your app because of this.  Fix is to upgrade to a newer release of the library.

Comment: how to resolve this in a react native android project

Comment: Note the fully qualified name of these new constants for imports, like [android.content.Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#RECEIVER_EXPORTED)

Comment: RECEIVER_EXPORTED and RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED require API level 33

Answer (score 21):

You can also add SDK Version Check

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
     registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
}else {
     registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter)
}
```

Comment: Please, add `@Suppress("UnspecifiedRegisterReceiverFlag")` to `else` branch.

Comment: Pls can someone tell me which file should i edit in a Flutter project?

Answer (score 16):

You can register a broadcast receiver without branching for Android versions using ContextCompat:

```
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED)
```

or

```
ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, broadcastReceiver, intentFilter, ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)
```

Answer (score 10):

I got this error when using Android Billing. It was solved by changing this:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.0'
```

...to this:

```
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  ContextCompat.registerReceiver(
this,
mMessageReceiver,
filter,
ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
)

It works for me

Answer (score -6):

I have added a Try Catch block to the lines displayed in the error logs, and it is now operational.